# jQuery .click() event not working in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, click

My simple HTML code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#imageUpload').click();return false;">Photo Upload</a>
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" multiple accept="image/*">
```

My Android MainActivity class in MainActivity.java:

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebapp/");

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfect in Chrome Desktop and Chrome Mobile.

But there is a problem at WebView

Is there any simple and quick solution

Comment: @deviato ???????

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try put

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebapp/");
```

after

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```